# RestKit add custom header for all requests?

Tags: ios, request, restkit

I am using `RestKit` for my iOS app.
I would like to add a custom header for **all** requests.

Is it possible to add a single header in one place and have all my RestKit requests use it? If so, where do I add the code?
If not -  do I have to add a header for every single request I make?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the header on the client that the RKObjectManager creates, after initializing the RKObjectManager:

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:@"https://mycompany.example.com/rest/"];

[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"X-AUTH-TOKEN" value:@"abc123"];
```

You don't need to subclass the AFHTTPClient.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by using custom *AFHTTPClient*. Create a subclass of *AFHTTPClient* and rewrite **requestWithMethod:path:parameters:** method like this:

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                                      path:(NSString *)path
                                parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
{
    [self setDefaultHeader:@"X-USER-TOKEN" value:userToken];
    return [super requestWithMethod:method
                               path:path
                         parameters:parameters];
}
```

Then initialize object manager with it:

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [[RKObjectManager alloc]
   initWithHTTPClient:customHttpClient];
```